# HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError works only once on periodical tasks

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have a couple of applications that run in specified intervals. To monitor OutOfMemoryError i've decided to enable HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, and before doing this i decided to do some research. Some of applications have maximum heap size of 2GB, so generating multiple heap dumps in rapid succession could eat up all disk space.

I've written a small script to check how it will work.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test implements Runnable{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                new Thread(new Test()).start();
        }

        public void run() {
                while (true) {
                        try{
                                List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
                                while (true){
                                        list.add(new Object());
                                }
                        }
                        catch (Throwable e){
                                System.out.println(e);
                        }
                        try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

                        }
                }
        }
}
```

And here is the result

```
$ java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx2M Test                                                                                                                                                        
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid25711.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [14694890 bytes in 0,101 secs]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

It works as i would want it to, but i would like to know why.

Looking at openjdk6 source code i've found the following

```
void report_java_out_of_memory(const char* message) {
  static jint out_of_memory_reported = 0;

  // A number of threads may attempt to report OutOfMemoryError at around the
  // same time. To avoid dumping the heap or executing the data collection
  // commands multiple times we just do it once when the first threads reports
  // the error.
  if (Atomic::cmpxchg(1, &out_of_memory_reported, 0) == 0) {
    // create heap dump before OnOutOfMemoryError commands are executed
    if (HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError) {
      tty->print_cr("java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: %s", message);
      HeapDumper::dump_heap_from_oome();
    }   

    if (OnOutOfMemoryError && OnOutOfMemoryError[0]) {
      VMError err(message);
      err.report_java_out_of_memory();
    }   
  }
}
```

How does the first if statement work?

EDIT: it seems that heapdump should be created every time message is printed, but it does not happen. Why is that so?

Answer (score 3):

The if statement contains a compare-and-exchange atomic operation which will return 0 if and only if the exchange was performed by the running thread. Compare-and-exchange (also known as compare-and-swap) works the following way:

- Supply a value of which you think a variable contains (0 in your case, the variable is out_of_memory_reported)
- Supply a value for which you would like to exchange the value (1 in your case)
- If the value is the one you supplied, it is exchanged for the replacement value **atomically** (no other thread may change the value after it has been compared against your estimation) and 0 is returned
- Otherwise, nothing happens and a value different from 0 is returned to indicate the failure

Comment: So if out_of_memory_reported is 0 it will be replaced with 1 and block will execute, and if it is 1 it will not be replaced and block will not execute?

Comment: @Blin Exactly, and the comparison and eventual exchange occur atomically thus no two threads can find the value to be 0.

Comment: So why is "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" printed every time but heapdump is created only once?

Comment: @Blin Could it be printed from somewhere else?

Comment: @biziclop theoreticaly, but i have'nt found any mentions of it in the source code.

Comment: @Blin I think the fact that the heap dump is only created once indicates that the condition in the if-statement works properly and the other messages are printed somewhere else as biziclop said, but I don't know where though.

Comment: @Blin The message "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" is printed from your catch block: `System.out.println(e);`. Nice investigation by the way. Very helpful!